# pixel to pixel transformation

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, pixel, distance, transformation

I am having a problem transferring the position of some objects in still  image (RGB image ) into 2D view of the room where the image had been taken.I have the coordinates of about 3 objects in the image (i mean X,y coordinate ) as well as the distance between them and I want to transfer the position of these 3 objects into the plan view .

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to clarify your question, but if I'm reading it the right way, it coult be as simple as taking the ratio from one object to another.

For example, if your sensor is 640px wide, and that covers a horizontal length of 10 meters, then you know that every 64 pixels represents one meter in the real world.

Bare in mind that this assumes the objects in the real world are at in the same plane, orthogonal to the lens vector. If objects are in different planes (depths), then you have a bigger problem in your hands.